# Connecting MySQL on EC2 instance to Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ec2

I am very new to AWS, and I am trying to connect my Rails app to a MySQL Database created directly on an AWS EC2 instance, not on RDS (which would have made it much easier to remotely connect via RDS database instance).

The mySQL db was set up for scraping by an outsourced dev, who doesn't know about RDS. Is there a way for me to create RDS instance that looks at the already-existing mySQL db, or for me to access this db directly from my Rails app? I use Heroku to deploy, if that makes any difference.

I was able to use `ssh cli` to access the EC2 ubuntu instance, then connect to mysql after that:

`ssh -i path/to/credentials/scrapy-aws-keypair.pem ubuntu@52.xx.xxx.xx` and `mysql -u root -p *****`, which works great. However, when I try the following

`development_sec:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: my_database
  encoding: utf8
  username: root
  password: xxxxxxxx
  host: ec2-52-xx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306`

and try to conect, I get `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ec2-52-xx-xxx-xx.us-east-x.compute.amazonaws.com'`

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to the EC2 instance and set the port of the connection to your MySQL DB's port (3306 default)

Comment: I have updated the question. Yes I tried to connect and got an error. It seems like MySQL has a few security settings that prevent authentication without ssh...or something?

Comment: Check if the firewall is not blocking the mysql connection. If that's good, it could be that you are not using your keypair.pem file for connection. I don't know if it is possible to use that ssh key for mysql. Try generating another ssh key on your server and use that for the mysql connection. Your key on your machine would be in the .ssh directory